# Is there any benefit for using 1x1 convolution over FC?

Tags: convolution

I see several authors describe their deep learning models with fully connected layer, but when they implement it, they use 1 by 1 convolution with stride 1 instead, I understand that, mathematically they are the same.

My question is, is there any benefit for using 1x1 convolution over FC?

From what I can see, it doesn't reduce memory usage, nor need less operations to compute:

Suppose that `v` is a vector of size `C` (channels), and we want to produce `M` channels, without counting bias:

- for conv net, for each output channel, it requires `C` multiplications, `C-1` additions, thus the number of operations is `M * C_mul + M * (C-1)_add`
- for FC, since it is a matrix multiplied by a vector, it also requires this  much operations

Memory wise, they both use `C * M` floats